# constant increase in memory while uploading images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, nsdata

I am uploading multiple images on server. When I upload about 100 images the memory rises to about 300 mb and even after uploading is done memory is not getting free. I am using `NSData` while uploading images and my images are stored in sqlite db.
How can reduce the memory spikes?

this is my piece of code

```
 - (void)_startUpload:(NSString *)filePath  {

        NSLog(@"sdf  filepath :   %@",filePath);
        arr=[ImagesAccount getAllMovies];

        for (int j=0; j<ma.count; j++) {

            NSLog(@"sdf  in d _startUpload ma[j] :   %@",ma[j]);
            [self startupuploader:ma[j]];
        }
    }


-(void)startupuploader:(NSString *)filePath{
        @autoreleasepool {

        image=YES;

        NSLog(@"filepath in flicke : %@",filePath);

        // JPEGData = [[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]autorelease];
        // NSLog(@"JPEGData in flicke : %@",JPEGData);
        // NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
        // NSLog(@"data in flicke : %@",data);

        snapPictureButton.enabled = NO;

        snapPictureDescriptionLabel.text = @"Uploading";

        self.flickrRequest.sessionInfo = kUploadImageStep;

        self.authorizeDescriptionLabel = nil;

        self.snapPictureDescriptionLabel=nil;

        self.authorizeButton=nil;

        self.snapPictureButton=nil;

        self.albumName=nil;

        self.imageView=nil;

        self.albumhome=nil;

        arrs=nil;

        [self.flickrRequest uploadImageStream:[NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:filePath] suggestedFilename:@"Flickr" MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" arguments:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0", @"is_public", nil]];

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;

        [self updateUserInterface:nil];

        }

    }
```

Comment: Any danger of seeing the code?

Comment: As your code is still hidden. A random guess is - `NSData` was not deallocated.

Comment: Have you tried Instruments? (The code profiling tool available in Xcode). It's pretty easy to use for finding large memory leaks like that.

Comment: And `uploadImageStream` returns nothing to indicate error? I assume you are using [this API](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr) (huge detail missing from your question).  Looking at the README, it seems to indicate a delegate that is used to get the results of the upload.  Show that code too.

Comment: Is the `uploadImageStream:` method asynchronous? If so, you end up doing all of your image uploads concurrently. That will cause all of your image data to be loaded at the same time.

Comment: trojanfoe- u are right i am using the same api . uploadImageStream is asynchronous.. I am not getting what will release the memory

Comment: @user2728950: I have explain in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921227/table-view-images-never-being-released/26925176#26925176