# How to clean up view controllers after swiping UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, memory, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I've implemented a full screen page view controller that creates view controllers as needed and they're cleaned up such that only 3 are in memory at once (current, previous, next). It's just like Apple's paged based application template. But I have programmatically added images and labels and buttons to each view controller I instantiate, in addition to setting an image for a `UIImageView` that exists for all of the pages. I just noticed when I swipe through the view controllers, memory is not cleaned up so by the time you reach the last view controller memory usage is up to 200 MB. If I comment the code out that creates the UI for each controller so they're all just a simple view controller with a background, memory usage is not increased as you swipe between the pages.

How can I clean up the content of the view controllers as the user swipes to ensure only a maximum of 3 are in memory at once? Or what have I done wrong to prevent this clean up from occurring if it should have been done automatically?

This is how I create the view controller for each index:

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> DataViewController {
    let dataVC = DataViewController(nibName: "DataViewController", bundle: nil)
    dataVC.index = index

    return dataVC
}
```

Then in `DataViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` I and add various elements to its `view` as appropriate based on its `index` property. For example:

```
if self.index == 1 {
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image1") //all pages have an image view, it's set up in DataViewController's XIB
    //programmatically create an image view, set its image, add auto layout constraints
    //add some buttons and labels and set up auto layout constraints
} else if self.index == 2 {
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
    //add images, buttons, labels etc
} ...
```

Comment: @Swipesight I converted my UIImage(named) code to use contentsOfFile and that has helped. Now it gets up to about 110 MB. Do you spot anything else that would help reduce that?

Comment: @Swipesight I was going to do just that, but it won't allow me to override dealloc nor viewDidUnload. How else could you check in Swift?

Comment: @Swipesight Yup `deinit` is called as you'd expect - page 0 is deallocated upon swiping to index 2 etc.

Comment: Maybe you should use Instruments to find out where your memory goes.

Comment: Check my answer about memory precautions. May be it helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921227/table-view-images-never-being-released/26925176#26925176

Comment: i had the same problem my case i have more than 600 page with images and memory goes up to 300MB but now with contentsOfFile every thing working very well thanks thanks thanks :)