# In my iPhone application. why i am getting the "Received memory warning"?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, didreceivememorywarning, memory-warning

I am getting this warning in iPhone app "[651:57011] Received memory warning". can any body please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Because your application required more resources in terms of memory but your device won't capable of to deliver it.

Comment: @kampai thank you for the response. after launching the application it is executing successfully but when the second time i am trying take picture with camera it is showing this warning.

Comment: Yes, that's the point where you have to start to looking for memory leaks. You should use instrument tool for that. Take a look on my answer to release memory resource.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921227/table-view-images-never-being-released/26925176#26925176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the low memory space of your device and the inefficient memory management.

Select `Product --> Analyse` for checking memory leaks.

Hope this may help you

Comment: I dont know why someone downvote this answer. Sounds good to me