# GPUImage memory error

Tags: ios, iphone, image-processing, memory-management, gpuimage

I am adding distortion effects to frame images of a recorded video on iOS. For 14 sec videos with resolution of 640 x 640 the app crashes with a memory error. I think that all memory gets properly deallocated.

I find it very strange that the profiler tells me that the app is consuming around 20 MB max! Also I can find no memory leaks. The CoreImage lib does accumulate around 580 MB of memory during the whole processing time, but the memory gets released after every processed frame, so that should not lead to crashing.

If I comment the distortion filters out, everything works fine, so I am assuming the error is in the filtering part. I am testing on an iPhone 5s with iOS 8 installed.

Is this a bug in GPUImage?
How come I can not profile the excessive memory consumption?

I am grateful for every answer! :)

This is the relevant piece of code:

```
- (CIImage *) render:(CIImage*)targetImage imageContext:(CIContext*) imageContext
        facialFeatures:(NSArray*)facialFeatures currentFrameInd:(int)frameInd
{
    if ( !facialFeatures ) return targetImage;

    @autoreleasepool {
        CGImageRef inputImage = [imageContext createCGImage:targetImage fromRect:[targetImage extent]];

        GPUImagePicture *sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithCGImage:inputImage];
        GPUImageOutput *currentOutput = sourcePicture;

        // Search through multiple faces.
        for ( ArtechFacialFeature *facialFeature in facialFeatures ) {
            // Create the distortion for one face.
            for ( ArtechImageDistortionDescription *distortion in distortions ) {
                GPUImageFilter *imageFilter = [self createDistortionFilter:distortion
                    facialFeature:facialFeature imageExtent:targetImage.extent];

                [currentOutput addTarget:imageFilter];
                currentOutput = imageFilter;
            }
        }

        [currentOutput useNextFrameForImageCapture];
        [sourcePicture processImage];

        UIImage *currentFilteredVideoFrame = [currentOutput imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];

        targetImage = [targetImage initWithCGImage:currentFilteredVideoFrame.CGImage];

        [sourcePicture removeAllTargets];

        currentFilteredVideoFrame = nil;
        sourcePicture = nil;

        currentOutput = nil;

        CFRelease( inputImage );
    }

    return targetImage;
}
```

Comment: This answer will help you to take memory precautions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921227/table-view-images-never-being-released/26925176#26925176

Comment: Thanks for you comment Kampai! I think that all memory gets properly deallocated. I can find no leaks or excess memory consumption in the profiler. That is the part that really bugs me. :(

Comment: I guess reason for consumption of more memory would be `nested for ` structure. Try to reformat it, either in a block way or in background. I'm not sure about the `GPUImageFilter` memory structure - it may possible that it uses cache too.

Comment: The for-loops create between 1-3 filters, which get chained together. Should not bust the memory completely. I added the autorelease pool, so that memory gets deallocated after each frame processing.

Comment: AFAIK `GPUImageFilter` should not be cached. Even if it was, it should get released on memory pressure?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that leaps out at me is that you're creating a new image and an array of new filters on every single incoming frame. This is going to be horribly inefficient and may overload the internal framebuffer caching system in GPUImage.

Instead, create a filter chain starting from a GPUImage texture input. Allocate the filters once and merely change their properties on each new frame. For the input, if you render your Core Image output into an OpenGL ES context that's backed by a texture and then feed that texture into GPUImage, you'll avoid an incredibly expensive (memory-, and performance-wise) GPU->CPU->GPU path and keep everything on the GPU.

With filters created once and reused for each frame, the internal framebuffer caching mechanism should be able to cap memory usage at a constant and relatively low value.

There may indeed be a leak due to a degenerate case here (I don't often build up and tear down filters with this frequency, so there may be a race condition in the deallocation), but trying to rework this to reuse filters will probably be a better way to go in any case.

Regarding the 20 MB value you're reporting, that's most likely from the Allocations instrument, which hides OpenGL ES memory usage. Look instead at Memory Monitor for a true read of your total application memory usage. I bet it will be a lot higher.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, Brad!!

I changed the code to create the filter chain once a the beginning of processing. (400 and something frames) Unfortunately with the same result. (I double checked that the filters get created only once!)

I have not implemented your suggestion to use `GPUImageTextureInput`, because I do not currently know the Texture ID of the input image. I was under the impression that AVFoundation loads the video frames to the frame buffer directly? I am happy with the perfomance currently, but could the use of `GPUImagePicture` be a source for the memory error?

Comment: I am somewhat new to Apple/iOS development and could not find the Memory Monitor Instrument? Is it maybe discontinued? The activity monitor shows the "Real Memory Usage", and that is supposed to show CPU and GPU memory consumption if I understand correctly. It is still around 20MB for the app right before it crashes.

Comment: @Senad - If you don't need to pass your video frames through Core Image for processing before you send them into GPUImage, you can instead use a GPUImageVideoCamera and take the pixel buffers from that and hand those to Core Image in parallel. It looks like you're using the facial feature detection, and if that's all you need, this will work well. The FilterShowcase example has a sample of how to do exactly this.

Comment: Also If I reduce the video resolution by 100 pixels for testing, I can process the video, but get a lot of memory warnings near the end. When processing the next video I get the same result. So it is not a premanent memory allocation / leak, but rather that builds up to fast during processing time. Your thought and comments will be greatly appreciated!! :)

Comment: @Senad - Regarding Memory Monitor, it looks like that's been merged into Activity Monitor. That gives you an accurate total read of real memory size. You might need to have it track the inspection head to monitor at specific points of time in your application's execution, if you want to review this over time.

Comment: Regarding Core Image: Thx for the hint. I am not sure, if I can apply it, since I am post-processing videos instead of direct capturing. I will have a look at it tomorrow, though. I can cirumvent the problem by reducing video resolution. But it would be really interesting to find the root cause, since I have been on it quite some time now. :)

Answer (score -2):

```
- (void)addObservers {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                            name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                          object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:)
                                            name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                          object:nil];
}

- (void)removeObservers {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self
                                               name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                             object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self
                                               name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                             object:nil];
}
```

Comment: sorry but this answer seems not related to the question