# App crash in iPhone4s while downloading images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sdwebimage

I'm using `SDWebImage` for asynchrony download images from server. I've tested the app in iPhone 5 and 5s with `iOS 8.1` and working fine, no memory warning at all.But i given build to client(using iPhone 4s) and he faces some crash while loading images, unfortunately i don't have iPhone 4s so can't figure out the problem. I tested in instruments with iPhone5 and here is screen shots after several run.[image: screen shot using iPhone 5]
And here is my code for download image

```
-(void)setImageWithUrl:(NSURL*)imgurl onImageView:(UIImageView*)image prograssive:(BOOL)progressive
{

    __block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

    __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = image;

    SDWebImageOptions opt;
    if (progressive) {

        opt = SDWebImageProgressiveDownload;
    }
    else
        opt = SDWebImageRetryFailed;

    [image sd_setImageWithURL:imgurl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_image"] options:opt progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
     {
         if (!activityIndicator)
         {
             [weakImageView addSubview:activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView.alloc initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]];
             activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(weakImageView.frame.size.width /2, weakImageView.frame.size.height/2);
             // activityIndicator.center = weakImageView.center;
             [activityIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
             [activityIndicator startAnimating];

         }
     }
                    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
     {

         [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
         activityIndicator = nil;
     }];
}
```

I did cleared memory in `didRecdeiveMemoryWarnig` method

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    NSLog(@"memory warning received in voucher");
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearMemory];
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] cleanDisk];
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] setValue:nil forKey:@"memCache"];
}
```

But it still crashes in iPhone 4s.Can any one guid me what do?

Comment: Add Crashlytics for your test app, and collect the crash report, then analyze the crash will be the most steady solution.

Comment: I'm trying to login but it says "you are on the list", i don't have Crashlytics account and trying to create, but didn't receive invitation.

Comment: May be this will help to sort our memory issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921227/table-view-images-never-being-released/26925176#26925176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your App is being killed due to memory pressure. Maybe try using an [Autorelease Pool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) to mitigate any memory spikes, since I think what you are doing in *didReceiveMemoryWarning* doesn't really help in those situation.