# Dismiss ViewController after transition to release memory

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

I want to free up memory my ViewController used after dismissing it. I use the following code to present the new ViewController and dismiss the old one:

```
let sB: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newVC: UIViewController = sB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyVC")
self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: { x in
    oldVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { _ in //oldVC: variable keeping track of currently visible view controller
        print("done")
    })
})
```

This code successfully presents `newVC` and prints `done` after dismissing `oldVC`. However, my memory still stays as high as it was when having `oldVC` on screen.
What am I doing wrong?

### FYI

- I am using [ENSwiftSideMenu](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu)

  - Since I didn't get it to work in a different way, **all my  ViewControllers are a subclass of ENSideMenuNavigationController**
- I am getting console warnings about detached views and views not being in the window hierarchy
- for all ViewControllers, both `presentingViewController` and `presentedViewController` are `nil`

Comment: What is the reference of the oldVC ?

Comment: What do you mean by "reference"? It is a global variable that is set to `self` in each ViewController's `viewWillAppear(_:)` method. Hence, it is of type `UIViewController

Comment: Try to add this line  deinit {
    debugPrintln("Clean")
}

Comment: Add to the oldVC's code?

Comment: yes in this case we could see when oldVC will be really dealcoated

Comment: Not printing anything…

Comment: Probably you have strong reference to this viewController

Comment: What's that mean?

Comment: http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/debugging-retain-cycles-in-objective-c-four-likely-culprits/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124047/discussion-between-linus-g-and-oleg-gordiichuk).

Comment: have you tried to make oldVcC to weak?

weak var OldVC = self

Comment: Yes. It already is a weak variable

Comment: To reduce memory foot prints this can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921227/table-view-images-never-being-released/26925176#26925176

Answer (score 6):

Check the following issues:

1. You should dismiss the old ViewController before present a new ViewController, or you will dismiss the new one at the same time.
2. Swift using ARC to manage memory. The oldVC is not released since some objects have a strong reference to it. Make an example, i have a ViewController with a variable tableView. The tableView will release when the ViewController released. But at the same time if you link it to another ViewController that is not released, the tableView will not release although the previous ViewController is released.

**Solution:**

1. Present a `UINavigationController` and using `setViewControllers` to manage the transition of your ViewControllers.
2. Remove the useless reference of the `oldVC`

If you really do not understand. You can search:

1. ARC
2. UIViewController transition

Comment: When dismissing before presenting I'm left with a blank screen.

Comment: @LinusG. Because both the old and new controllers are dismissed after you call the dismiss function.

Comment: So what am I gonna do?

Comment: @LinusG. My suggestion is to put both old and new controllers to a UINavigationController to arrange your transitions. If you do want use present. You can try  dismiss the old controller without an animation and present the controller in its completion closure.

Comment: The latter is exactly what I did. I will try with the nav though.

Comment: @LinusG. Try this, not use oldVC to dismiss.  self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { _ in //oldVC: variable keeping track of currently visible view controller
    self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: { x in
        
    })
    print("done")
})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124426/discussion-between-linus-g-and-).

Comment: @LinusG. Do you fix your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, nope.

Comment: @LinusG.  Please see my code first. https://codeload.github.com/Moonsownner/Test1/zip/master

Comment: @LinusG. Hi, i`m back, do you get through the problem?

Comment: So do you still want fix the same problem? What is it going on now?

Comment: Yes of course. Any other ideas how to regarding my FYI section in the post?

Comment: Let`s chat in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124426/discussion-between-linus-g-and-

Answer (score 3):

Your `oldVC` will not be deallocated, since your `newVC` (and any `UIViewController`) keeps by default a strong reference to its `presentingViewController` - the controller that presented it. If this was not the case, you would never be able to safely dismiss your `newVC` without disturbing the view hierarchy.

As far as your specific problem is concerned, in order to deallocate your old view controller, I would suggest dismissing the `oldVC` first and then display your `newVC` from another ViewController, earlier in the stack (could be the `UIApplication shared().keyWindow?.rootViewController`)

Comment: Well I am getting a warning saying sth. about the view not being in window hierarchy. Until now I wasn't able to fix that issue and since it never caused any problems I didn't really have to.

Comment: @LinusG. It is indeed issued as a warning (although in my experience it can result in errors)

Comment: Presenting from `rootViewController` leaves me w/ a blank screen :(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue for `UINavigationController`'s push/pop. @spassas is right about the strong reference which is the reason your `newVC` is not deallocated. You should look at the `newVC` closely.

In my case (written in Objective-C) there was another view controller referenced as a private property of the pushed view controller (your `newVC`):

```
EventActionSheetViewController* actionSheet;
```

That `actionSheet` had a strong reference to the pushed view controller (`newVC`) as its delegate:

```
@property (nonatomic) id<EventActionSheetDelegate> delegate;
```

I've been checking my app's memory and found that the pushed view controller wasn't deallocated after being popped by the navigation controller. After a few hours I changed the strong reference to weak and it worked out:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<EventActionSheetDelegate> delegate;
```

The problem was that my pushed view controller and its `EvenetActionSheetViewController` had strong references to each other and somehow did not let each other deallocate.

I recommend you to check if your `newVC` has similar strong references loops and change them to weak where possible. In Swift use `weak let` or `weak var` instead of `let/var`. Hope this will help you find the bug.

Comment: I did change my declaration to `weak var` but that doesn't change anything apparently.

Comment: @LinusG. I think we need to see some code of the `newVC` to help

Comment: What do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your code with the following:

```
    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let sB: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newVC = sB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyVC")
    appDel.window?.rootViewController = newVC
    appDel.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Hope this works !

EDIT : 
You can also check that the old View Controller is being de-initialized by adding the following code to all the View Controllers :

```
    deinit {
        debugPrint("Name_Of_View_Controller deinitialized...")
    }
```

EDIT 2:

If you want to preserve the flow of presentation in view controllers and you only want to dismiss the last view controller, i.e.,

In a transition : masterVC -> oldVC -> newVC

And after the transition from oldVC to newVC, you want to return back to masterVC, freeing up memory by oldVC.
You can pass the masterVC reference to the oldVC and achieve what you want to as following:

```
if(masterVC != nil) {
         oldVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
            let sB: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let newVC = sB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc2")
            self.masterVC!.present(newVC, animated: false, completion: {
                print("done")
            })
        })
}
```

This works for the case you stated.

Comment: Which one is not working for you? The first one, or the second one?
And do you have any strong references in the oldVC ?